# How to Write a Shell Script to Move Files from FTP Server to Network Share Drive

Tags: networking, command-line, scripts, ftp

I have customers who upload large amounts of data to my FTP server (an Ubuntu 9.10 machine).  Once the files are uploaded, I am faced with transferring them to a local Droboshare network drive so our technical support staff can retrieve them and analyze the issue.

After I mount the network share at `/media/<sharename>` I run this command manually to get these files:

`sudo mv /home/ftp/<data_dir>/<file_name> /media/<network_share>/<ftp_user_data>`

but this takes forever and if there are tens or hundreds of files, I can't realistically do this over and over again.  I thought it would be nice to have a script that I could run periodaclly to transfer a group of these files to the network share.  I can sort them as the technical support staff uses them.

I am still new to Linux and writing shell scripts.  Anyway to do this easily?  Just to add to the description here, the files could be **ZIP files**, **FASTA files**, **TAR.GZ files**, and/or **TXT files**.  Also, if the ZIP files are large, certain zipping programs convert these to **ZIP.001**, **ZIP.002**, **ZIP.003**, etc...  So the file type in this FTP directory could be quite varied.

I was thinking the way I can identify these files is by simply transferring ALL files in the directory (although this may take a while) or to somewhat designate a subset of these, according to time completed or something like this.

I'm open to ideas.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using sudo?

Comment: What ftp-server are you using? there are ~6-7 different ftp-server programs in the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just make the FTP folder the actual mount point for the network drive? I run into a similar issue where I'm constantly backing up VirtualMachines on a Linux machine to a Windows network share (since the majority of the company infrastructure is Windows). This is my structure:

`/media/windows-share` is my mount point

For continuity I've created a symlink in my backup application:

`/opt/backup/mnt` so if the mount point changes in the future my program doesn't need an update.

Lastly I employ a cool little tool called [`autofs`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) (`sudo apt-get install autofs`) That guide is decent (and up to date) - though I've employed this with a slightly different approach on my [blog](http://marcoceppi.com/blog/2010/05/automount-me-baby/).

In your case I would create a symlink where my FTP dropbox is (`/home/ftp/<data_dir>/`) to the appropriate network folder in `/media/<network_share>/<ftp_user_data>` that way there's no wasted time in transferring across disks and the files are available immediately.

Comment: +1 for removing a step rather than fixing a step :) Simplifying, always good, is.

Comment: This is a great answer...  Almost done making it work.  One thing.  In your blog, you used `-fstype=cifs` and this worked for me too.  But when I manually mount these shares, I use `smbfs` yet when I tried to add this method to the auto.nfs file it didn't work.  Any idea why?

Comment: @nicorellius `smbfs` and `cifs` are basically the same thing. `smbfs` is being depreciated to `cifs` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba

Comment: I thought I had it working...  But now I can't seem to create that symlink.  Getting error:  "hard link not allowed for directory."  Could you provide some more details exactly how this is setup?

Comment: @Marco Ceppi:  I also was able to mount the network share to the local linux directory `/home/ftp/<data_dir>` but when I tried to transfer a file to it using FTP, my FTP client threw an error and the operation failed.  I may be confused on how to set these permissions.  Do I set them on `/home/ftp/<data_dir>` or on `//server/<network_share>/ftp_user_data`?

Comment: @nicorellius You don't want to make the mount the FTP destination. You want to soft link the mount point (something in `/mnt` or `/media` as I used in my example) Then `ln -s /media/mntpoint/other_dir_on_mnt /home/ftp/somethignhere` I found that autofs had troubles detecting when to mount when a script or other process was trying to access the mount directly.

Answer (score 4):

For duplicating files from here to there (or there to here), [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) is a swiss army chainsaw which will likely do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to process files as soon as they're uploaded to the FTP, using a technology sucha s inotify. `inoticoming` is a tool you can use for that, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/inoticoming.1.html.